# Implied volatility

Tags: implied-volatility, local-volatility

I have a question about calculating the implied vol. Assuming the implied vol that a option will expire in 1 day is $\sigma_1$, and the implied vol that the option will expire in 2 days is $\sigma_2$. Is there a way to calculate the implied vol from day 1 to day 2 when it has skew?  I know I can compute the local vol from day 1 to day 2 and may transform it to implied vol. But is there a more straight forward way to do it? Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no easy way. As you mention you should: calibrate your LV model to the vanilla options expiring at $t_1$ and $t_2$, price forward starts under the calibrated LV model and finally imply their BS volatility. Although it cannot harm to use LV in the particular case of very short term forward dynamics, I would not recommend it for the estimation of forward skew in general. I'd rather stochastic volatility models like Heston. It's a good exercise to compare the types of forward smiles generated by the two models.

Comment: As a (presumably not arbitrage free) approximation, you could also compare with, for a fixed forward moneyness level $k$, computing $\sigma_{12}^2(k)$ as $(\sigma_2^2(k) t_2 - \sigma_1^2(k) t_1)/(t_2-t_1)$. The key here is to understand that vanilla option prices (that only depend on the **terminal** distribution) embed **no information related to forward volatility**. So you always need additional modelling assumptions to derive forward volatilities (except if you use forward volatility sensitive derivatives like forward starts etc.).